# Storing and retrieving Gujarati Characters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to send notifications to a user in the Gujarati Language. Currently, I am able to send them in English Language but can't able to send in the Gujarati language.

I have searched on this, and what I got is python2 stores them as ASCII characters not as ASCII numbers. So, how to deal with that?

Even any other way to do this is helpful.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All typeable languages can be encoded using unicode. I do not know Gujarati, but it is the same concept using French.

```
temp = u'aâbéx'.encode('utf-8')
print(temp.decode('utf-8'))
```

> 'aâbéx'

Comment: This Work! This can be used with any typeable language. Thanks @JahKnows

Comment: I assume this will only work in python2.7, can I know how I would execute the same in python 3.7